# How to insert tiles attributes into a nested jsp?

Tags: java, jsp, model-view-controller, struts2, tiles

I've read several of the answers on this site and have yet to find a solution to inserting tiles attributes into nested jsp files:

My goal is to insert a couple of small strings (defined as tiles attributes in **tiles.xml**) within a tag in a jsp that is nested.

Example:

I have my **baseLayout.jsp** which looks like:

```xml
<tiles:insertAttribute name="header" />
<tiles:insertAttribute name="securePage" />
<tiles:insertAttribute name="body" />
<tiles:insertAttribute name="sessionTimeout"/>
<tiles:insertAttribute name="footer" />
```

Within my body.jsp I have the following:

```xml
<li>
    <s:url id="languageUrl" namespace="/prot" action="rs" >
        <s:param name="request_locale">
            <s:text name="html.lang.op" />
        </s:param>
    </s:url>
    <s:a href="%{languageUrl}" lang="<s:text name="html.lang.op" />">
        <s:text name="html.lang.full.op" />
    </s:a>
</li>
```

> **Simply put, I want to replace the `"/prot"` and `"rs"` values within the url tag to be inserted as tiles attributes (so each individual tiles definition will point to the correct action within this language toggle button).**

---

It should be simple, right? Well, I've been working on this for over 2 hours and it seems as though I can't use tiles attributes at all beyond the first (main) tiles template.

Is there any way I can declare a variable in the main template and simply call it instead of inserting directly from tiles?

Is there another solution?

**NOTE**: *this url tag within **body.jsp** is in the middle of it, and for certain reasons I can't split up **body.jsp** into two.*

Comment: The s:text nested in the s:a is a syntax error. It can't be your code.

Comment: @Andrea Ligios the above code is working perfectly. The s:text within the s:a causes no issues for me, and I have it in many locations.

Comment: Like Andrea said you cannot nest tags like you did in `lang` attribute. Besides that where and how do you use tiles tags? Also which version of S2?

Comment: @Aleksandr M Ohh I get what he was saying now. OK so I'll have to put them in variables instead of referring to attributes? I am using tiles tags in my baseLayout.jsp.. if I try any tiles tags within body.jsp I get an error (and it states online in several places I cannot do this). Struts 2.3.15